# why extra vertical scrollbar appears in mat-tab-body-content and I need to use overflow-auto height 100%

Tags: html, css, angular

my css

```
`.med-list-table-scroll {
 height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;  
}`
```

my html

```
`<div class="med-table-inner-container"
       [ngClass]="{'med-list-table-scroll': !dynamicPageSizing && scrollable,
                   'med-overflow-hidden': !dynamicPageSizing && !scrollable}"

>`
```

I need vertical scroll bar with height 100% and this is my html css

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then you have two scrolls, one most likely comes from the body, the other that you set. One of the reasons is because the heights are not related to each other. The `med-list-table-scroll` block will be 100% relative to its parent. If the parent is not at full height, then the children will be the same. Also check the parent's parents. I hope I was able to explain.

Comment: Thanks for answering.Parent's height is also 100%.Its working for all 90% 80% height but with that height view is not good.When I m giving 100% height the scrollbar disappears.